# Push changes from Staging to Live

Tags: magento2.4, magento2.3.5-p1, staging

I have a live website of Magento 2.3.5 p1 and created a staging of my live website and have updated it to 2.4.3 p1.

I would like to know how can I push the update changes from my staging website to live website without loosing any data such as new orders, invoices, customers & products.

Comment: what kind of changes you want to do ?

Answer (score 0):

There are different options

1. You can copy the staging changes and add manually to live
2. You can merge your staging branch into live.